# Mediocre Thesis Topic. Does this Hurt my Reputation

Tags: phd, thesis, research-topic

Just curious as to the effects of publishing a mediocre PHD thesis:

After sitting down and taking a cold, detached, look at my thesis topic, I realized I was given a pair of coobook-style problems, i.e., in order to answer the questions I was given to answer, I just need to go over a list of requirements and see if the general results apply to my specific problems. Instead of research level, the problems I was given look more like exercises at the end of a book; a graduate-level book, but still, cookbook.

Question: Once I am done with this, which shouldn't take more than a few months, how will this look to anyone going over the thesis? Since I will be having some extra time, I am considering doing some extra research and tacking it into the thesis. Is there something else I can do?

I suspect my advisor may not have  a very high opinion of me and thought I could not likely handle anything more complicated. This itself brings issues as to the recommendations I may receive when someone asks my advisor for a recommendation.

Comment: Have you been publishing your results in decent conferences/journals?

Comment: @AustinHenley: frankly, this is my first (sort-of) research-level paper.

Comment: If you are still in the early stages then who knows what your dissertation may become over the next several years.

Comment: @AustinHenley: Still, how can I extract juice out of a rock? I can follow the recipe and answer, but I am trying to see how to tack-on new research as I go on. Any other way I can improve on it? Sorry, I am not looking for obstacles, I can see how to answer the questions I was given, not because I am brilliant, but because it is too easy. I don't see off hand how to turn this answer into something of higher quality.

Comment: This is exactly what your advisor is for. You should have a conversation with him or her. If you don't feel comfortable with that, then you should question why you are working with this person.

Comment: P.S. Anything can be made interesting so I don't buy that your thesis topic is mediocre. Simple or straight forward also don't mean mediocre.

Comment: As a PhD student, you should be trying to do research that you find interesting.  This is not necessarily just a matter of following your advisor's instructions.  It's convenient if it is, but if it is not, then you should take the opportunity to learn how to select topics for yourself and become an independent researcher.  You will need to do this after the PhD anyway, so why not before?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't actually worked out these problems, so it's not clear how simple they will be.  If they are indeed easy, they may just be stepping stones to a bigger problem.  But if your estimate is a few months, then these problems are probably not totally trivial.  In any case, if you're not clear about the motivation for doing these problems, ask your advisor.

Comment: I agree I am "guilty" (responsible): I have not taken the initiative to do my research and I have not received any mentoring: I think it is a shared responsibility here both  for me to take initiative and for the advisor to guide me through. I think we both failed. @Trevor: problem is that you have limited time to finish your PHD and if you select a research project that goes nowhere, you may end up going through the rabbit hole, and end up without a PHD. So it makes more sense to let someone more experienced--your advisor--select the topic initially.I think you should try to make

Comment: that transition ultimately, but ideally, your advisor should lead you through the first steps.

Comment: _So it makes more sense to let someone more experienced--your advisor--select the topic initially._ — [citation needed] And what if your advisor selects a research topic that goes nowhere? Recovering from blind alleys is an integral part of the research process.

Comment: @JeffE: It is a matter of probabilities, as with everything else in life, there are no guarantees. Someone who is more experienced and who has already done research is more likely to come up with something productive. If I knew how to do research on my own and I needed no help, I would not need to go to Grad School; I would already be out there publishing papers.

Comment: @NeedBetterThesis. From my own personal experience, **my** students are **significantly** better off developing their own research problems than having me assign them.

Comment: And ther's a huge soectrum between an advisor assigning a problem and the student needing no help. Advisors are supposed to **advise**.

Comment: @Jeff E: Yes, ideally it would be a combination of initiative by the student and mentoring. I think in my case both aspects; both of us , failed in this respect. I was too passive, and he was not very helpful; both wrong.

Comment: Getting a PHD without any publications is the thing you should worry about. If you publish more than one good papers in good journals or conferences (CS) then your problem and the solutions proposed by you are valuable. And what is this? "Once I am done with this". Done with what? Have you actually published anything? Or writing a "mediocre" thesis is enough to get a PHD on your department? If yes, then you will have no research reputation anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A PhD is documentation that you can do your own research.  You don't have to take what you're given.  That said, maybe your advisor considers the "toy problems" a warmup for more advanced research?  You should talk to your advisor and also to other faculty members you trust.  Let them know that you are concerned your topic may be weak.  Perhaps they will have some ideas on how you can make it stronger.  Depending on the outcome of these discussions, you may want to shop around for a different advisor who is a better fit for you, both in research interests and personality.  The key is to take charge of your own dissertation.

Answer (score 3):

You sound like you're at the very early stages of the research process. Perhaps these problems are not as simple as they appear to be.

In any case, I think you're fretting prematurely. If your research topic ends up being less-than-stellar, you'll have plenty of opportunities to redeem yourself by doing more exciting work after you're done. To answer your question, I don't think a "mediocre" thesis topic would have long-lasting effects on your overall reputation, which will ultimately be judged by a much larger body of work.

From one of your comments:

> *if you select a research project that goes nowhere, you may end up going through the rabbit hole, and end up without a PhD*

This could happen if the project is too easy; this could happen if the problem is too hard. This could happen if someone else is doing research right now that will nullify your results before you're done. This could happen if you get burned out and don't finish your work. In some respects, completing a PhD is like a minefield; it's fraught with risk.

You can switch advisors, switch topics, or start doing the work your advisor assigned. Unless you have more than a hunch that this work will be fruitless, I'd recommend starting with the task you've been assigned, and not letting fears of your reputation 10 years down the road paralyze you from getting underway.